# How to import one function instead of whole file?

Tags: javascript, import, module

There is a function i want to export to other modules

index.js

```
export function addPageSwitchFunctionality() {
  for (let i = 0; i < pages.length; i++)
    pages[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
      if (event.target.innerText === "Home")
        document.location.href = "http://127.0.0.1:5500/public/";
      else
        document.location.href =
          "http://127.0.0.1:5500/public/" +
          event.target.innerText.toLowerCase();
    });
}

addPageSwitchFunctionality();
```

somePage.js

```
import { addPageSwitchFunctionality } from "../index.js";

addPageSwitchFunctionality();
```

My both files have type module in html. When i run somePage.js i get an error that says cannot read property style of null which is a line in index.js. That means my whole file gets imported into somePage.js. How can i prevent this and get only necessary stuff?

update:

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at index.js:165
```

line 165 index.js :

```
slideShow.style.backgroundImage = `url(${slideShowImages[slideIndex]})`;
```

Comment: Can you paste exactly what the error says?

Comment: Well, one would assume for javascript to know what things are exported and made available for you to import, it has to compile the entire source file.

Comment: Bigger question would be why is a file that is exporting a method, also executing said method?

Comment: Added error and critical line. For execution part, it is a navbar and i want to share a functionality between pages. I understand it needs to read the file in order to get exported function. The things is that export is at line 27, why it doesn't stop there after finding it? Is copying function as it is into other file the only solution?

Comment: @Taplar, only when i solved this i understood what you were saying. So what i was trying to do is define functions in home page, execute and export them from there instead of defining everything in separate file and importing it in both home page and and another page, silly me.

Answer (score 0):

Set `slideShow` to an object with a style property before or add `if (slideShow)`  at the beginning of index.js:165.

Comment: Need to add many if statements in this scenario as same type of error keeps popping up one after another

Comment: What else is being executed on load of the module?